# Django won't syncdb after adding a method to a model

Tags: python, django

When I add the check_stats() method manage.py hangs. The within_range() and light_check() functions are imported from a custom library. I've tried running syncdb with verbosity, but I receive no errors. I'm unable to stop the process with ctrl+c and have to close the terminal window. After this I'm no longer able to run any commands from manage.py without getting the same problem. I had another function in another file that did the same exact thing, but I wanted to use a method instead. I've deleted the db and tried syncing again and no db even gets created unless I remove that method.

```
class PlotZone(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    plot_comments = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    current_temp = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    current_humid = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    light_start = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    light_stop = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    light_status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    goal_temp = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    goal_humid = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    humid_alert = models.NullBooleanField(default=False)
    temp_alert = models.NullBooleanField(default=False)
    light_alert = models.NullBooleanField(default=False)
    alert_status = models.NullBooleanField(default=False)
    humid_fail_limit = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    temp_fail_limit = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def check_stats(self):
        if not within_range(self.goal_temp, self.current_temp, self.temp_fail_limit):
            self.alert_status = True
        elif not within_range(self.goal_humid, self.current_humid, self.humid_fail_limit):
            self.alert_status = True
        elif not light_check(self, datetime.time()):
            self.alert_status = True

def within_range(goal, current, fail_limit):
    goal = int(goal*10)
    current = int(current*10)
    fail_limit = int(fail_limit*10)
    lower_range = range((goal-fail_limit), goal+1)
    upper_range = range(goal, (goal+(fail_limit+1)))
    if (current in lower_range) or (current in upper_range):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Did you try passing the argument that displays the traceback?

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific. The verbosity argument? Yes, I did. It didn't show anything on 1, 2, or 3.

Comment: You may be locking a table at some point, I need to see the definition of `within_range()`

Comment: The traceback argument.

Comment: I added my within_range() function.

Comment: I think @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams is referring to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---traceback - if you add `--traceback`, you might get more information.

Comment: @CorySM, I think its indentation issue, can you please add `within_range()` inside class. As your script looks thats the issue.

Comment: within_range() isn't a part of the class. It's a function I've imported from a library I've made for this project.